# GTM Triggers Events x10 despite only a single click

Tags: google-tag-manager

I ran into this inconsistent behavior on my Gatsby site I have GTM set up to track events for GA4.
Here's my code

```
<button onClick={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'get_case_info'
  });
}}>
  See Info
</button>
```

And my tag and trigger settings:

[image]

[image]

It will get triggered a total of 11 times each time I click. What's more odd is that if I change the event name and set the trigger to occur on the changed name (see_case) then it only gets triggered once per click. It's odd because other events don't get triggered another 10 times on top of the initial event despite have the same setup of keeping a consistent name throughout the dataLayer event and Google Analytics event name.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. According [to the docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872?hl=en&utm_id=ad#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) you do not need to create the Custom Event in GA4 as well. The Custom Events are designed to trigger when a condition is met a lot like GTM. Say you want to record a conversion based on Purchases made in the US. You would create a new custom event called "US Purchases" then add the conditions for event_name equals 'purchase' and currency equals 'USD'. I assume the 10x was an infinite loop that Google added a limit to. My set up is correct with the data layer push going to the trigger then finally sending the event name to GA4.

The only thing you would need to add in GA4 was if you added some custom parameters to the event like so:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: 'get_case_info',
  caseNumber: 1234
})
```

You would set up the custom parameters to get tracked via the [custom dimensions set up](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209).